# How do I quit/exit all windows/buffers/splits/tabs at once in Vim or vimdiff?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

How do you quit all windows with a single command in Vim or `vimdiff`?

`:q` only quits out of the active window, so then a separate `:q` is needed to close each window.

Comment: Here's what I like to do - `:only` to show the final result of the merge, then `ZZ` to save and quit, since there is only one window open after `:only` command (or swap `ZZ` for however you like to quit a single window).

Answer (score 102, accepted):

`:qa` quits all open windows/buffers/splits/tabs
(aliases: `:qall` `:quitall`)

[Vim documentation for :qa](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:qa)

For help on this command in Vim: `:help :qa`

`:qa!` will quit without giving an option to save if it's modified.
`:wqa` will write all changed buffers and then quit.
`:wqa!` will write all changed buffers, even readonly ones, and then quit.

Comment: For those who don't know where to write `:qa`, first press `ctrl+C`.